# Windows agent crash by jnlp

Tags: jenkins

My master Jenkins is on an AWS server, when I connect the agents via jnlp, it disconnects after a short time and I have to launch them manually. Is it possible to prevent the nodes from crashing?

As a workaround I launched them as SSH into Windows but I need to map them to a Z directory that is connected to a Linux server

Comment: If your agent is crashing then you will have to check the error log which will be located in the same directory as Jenkins agent jar file. If you want help to understand the logs then you will have to update your question with logs file